# UIDynamics not working in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to convert the Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on UIDynamics to swift code, but I'm stuck on the very first part.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial

Here's what I'm doing:

1. created a square UIView
2. added a UIDynamicAnimator to the main view
3. added a UIGravityBehavior and initialized it with the square
4. added gravity behavior to the animator

It all compiles and runs fine but the square doesn't move. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

https://github.com/oisinlavery/UIDynamics-Swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created your animator as a local variable to your `go` method, so it disappears as soon as that method is finished. It needs to be an instance variable on your `ViewController` class so that it will stick around and do the work of animating the square:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var animator: UIDynamicAnimator?

    @IBAction func go(sender : UIButton) {
        var square = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.view.addSubview(square)

        self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)
        var grav = UIGravityBehavior(items:[square])

        self.animator!.addBehavior(grav)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nate, that did the trick. I didn't realise it would be removed when the method was finished. I'm coming from JS so still alot to learn but loving Swift so far.